# .htaccess rewrite rule causes endless loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want my .htaccess file to redirect to some page if any wildcard **as a subdomain** entry hit the browser.  i.e.  I want

> **sam**.xyz.com

To redirect to

> sam.xyz.com/view.php?id=**sam**

I am using following rewrite rules for redirect.

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz.com [NC]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).xyz.com
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /view.php?id=%1 [L,R]

Problem i am facing is that it does not shift to new domain keeping query string instead it generates an endless loop

> **sam**.xyz.com

redirects to

> http://**sam**.xyz.com/view.php?id=sam

But doesnt move to url above without endless loop.
Kindly help me out.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add a condition for redirect to prevent redirection loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/view\.php
```

the whole code would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).xyz.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/view\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view.php?id=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: page concatination solved but domain loses its query and cause endless loop.What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have added the same above rules still the same loop

Comment: oups , forgot a slash, try it now

Comment: thanks that works :) 
need one more help , how can i hide view.php?id=sam from the url keeping its value backend.

Comment: or atleast hide query string id=sam from address bar,can i?

Comment: yeh, just remove the R flag at the end of RewriteRule (replace [L,R] with [L]) ,  feel free to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Plus what if my view.php page locate in a directory as 
xyz.com/sam/view.php what changes are required? 
Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: maybe i did not understand correctly, you wanna to rewrite sam.xyz.com to sam.xyz.com/view.php?id=sam without changing the url adress at the client browser ? if yes, then removing `R` from my answer should  do the trick (clear the browser cache)

Comment: what about having view.php in sub directory,what changes are required?

Comment: just add '/sam' before '/view.php...' in the rewriterule.

Comment: Thanks that works  ,  Can I just omit query string after view.php as sam.xyz.com/view.php  keeping query variable at back end..?

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to: prefix.domain.tld/view.php?id=prefix

Ensure that the url does not contain: id=prefix.

This solution prevents, that someone call's the url: aaa.example.com/view.php?id=bbb

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).xyz.com
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^:]+)::.*id=\1
RewriteRule ^ /view.php?id=%1 [L,R]
```

Note: (.*) in the rewrite rule is obsolete.

Leave the R away to do not redirect the visitor to the url (/view.php?id=%1)

Comment: That helps , how can I hide query variable from url?